# ng2-currency-mask start typing to the left of the decimal place?

Tags: angular, concurrency

I am using ng2-currency-mask and I've noticed that if I start typing in a textbox it starts at the cents and then goes to dollars. For example, if I type 33 it will be $.33 instead of $33.00. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong? This seems to be the opposite of what I think it should be. Is there a way to reverse this? The input is of type="text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.
As far as I can tell, there's no configuration for changing this behavior.
If you're really interested, the code that handles input is [here](https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask/blob/master/src/input.handler.ts).

Comment: There is opened ISSUE https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask/issues/93 ... till 2 Mar 2018 (unsolved) :(

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and find the answer in the source of this directive.If you pass precision:0 to the options the decimal part will remove.

```
<input currencyMask  type="text" [options]="{precision:0}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

By default this configuration is fixed and there is no alternative in changing the configuration for this. The only solution to fix this is by adding dir="rtl" to the input field

```
<input currencyMask  type="text" dir="rtl" [options]="{prefix: '', suffix: ''}" />
```

By adding the above line you will be able to get the output the way you want